# BindingList.Clear performed Async causes DataGridView System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I need some help.
I have a DataGridView that is just a readonly one bind to a BindingList.
I first set the DataSource for the new list and them I add the Items to the list.
the Columns are generated automatically.
when I need to reload the page I just clear the list and add the items again.

if I perform the reload of the page sync with the UI it works fine but if I start a task and do it, calling Clear() on the BindingList fails with an exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233080
  Message=Index 0 does not have a value.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at InCare.UserControls.DataGridViewItemWrapper.DataGridViewOnRowsAdded(Object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs args) in C:\ws\Source\Repos\incare\Src\InCare.UserControls\DataGridViewItemWrapper.cs:line 40
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowPostPaint(DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle boundingRect, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle gridBounds, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleVerticalBorderAdded, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: `BindingList` is not threadsafe. That's why it fails.

Answer (score 2):

This is multi-threading issue.

`BindingList` is not thread-safe. When you're attempting to clear it from task, which works on worker thread, `DGV` attempts to read it from from UI thread.

You didn't post code, but the basic approach is to build some collection inside task, and return this collection to replace `BindingList` content.

**Do not** try to change `BindingList` from background thread:

```
private async Task<IList<SomeDataItem> GetDataItemsAsync()
{
    // do some work in background, e.g. call web service or database
    // ...
    return dataItems;
}

pirvate async void HandleRefreshButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataItems = await GetDataItemsAsync();

    // since we didn't call ConfigureAwait(false) for task,
    // the rest of method will run on UI thread
    bindingList.Clear();

    foreach (var item in dataItems)
    {
        bindingList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think so? It's Ok to use async with MVVM or similar patterns. But you should carefully deal with cross-thread operations. Moreover, often you don't need to update data-bound collection from worker thread. If your task fetches collection from web service or similar, it's just inefficient to repaint bound control on each item.